# Stacked bar chart , stacking by genre of games

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a video games sales data, I was able to chart video game sales by year however I want to do a stacked chart meaning one would know in a certain year how much was action game sale shooting games sales strategy games sales etc
Your help will be greatly appreciated

[Sales by Year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpE6U.png)

Sample Data:

```
,Year,Genre,Global_Sales
0,2006.0,Sports,82.74
1,1985.0,Platform,40.24
2,2008.0,Racing,35.82
3,2009.0,Sports,33.0
4,1996.0,Role-Playing,31.37
5,1989.0,Puzzle,30.26
6,2006.0,Platform,30.01
7,2006.0,Misc,29.02
8,2009.0,Platform,28.62
9,1984.0,Shooter,28.31
10,2005.0,Simulation,24.76
11,2005.0,Racing,23.42
12,1999.0,Role-Playing,23.1
13,2007.0,Sports,22.72
14,2009.0,Sports,22.0
15,2010.0,Misc,21.82
16,2013.0,Action,21.4
17,2004.0,Action,20.81
18,1990.0,Platform,20.61
19,2005.0,Misc,20.22


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('vgsales.csv')

df.dropna(subset = ['Year'], inplace=True)
df['Year']=df['Year'].astype(int)
df['Year']= df['Year'].astype(str)
df.set_index(['Year'],inplace=True)

df = df.groupby(['Year']).agg({'Global_Sales':np.sum}) #gives sales for each year

# df= df.groupby(['Year','Genre']).agg({'Global_Sales':np.sum}) # gives sales by each genre 
# gf = df.groupby('Genre')

# df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# df.sort_values(df.index, inplace=True)
# plt.bar(df.index.get_level_values(0), df['Global_Sales'])

lab = df.index.get_level_values(0)
y = df['Global_Sales']
x = np.arange(len(lab))
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

plt.bar(x,y)
plt.title('Video Game Sales in Past Years', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.ylabel('Sales (Millions)')
plt.xticks(x, lab, rotation = 'vertical')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using data from [Kaggle: Video Games Sales](https://www.kaggle.com/gulsahdemiryurek/video-game-sales-exploratory-data-analysis/data)

Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/kaggle/video_game_sales/vgsales.csv')

dfg = df.groupby(['Year','Genre']).agg({'Global_Sales':np.sum})

ax = dfg['Global_Sales'].unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(10,10))
plt.legend(title='Game Genre', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
ax.set_title('Global Sales')
ax.set_ylabel('Sales (Millions)')
ax.set_xlabel('Years')
```

[image]